# VBA checkbox name length limit

Tags: vba, excel

i have just simple question. Is here some limit in excel VBA to checkbox name?

i have code like this, and when im using name longer than 33 characters, i have error Unable to set the Name property of the checkbox class (its only a test code)

So is here some way to bypass this?

```
 Sub createTestBox()

    Dim shimSheet As Worksheet
    Set shimSheet = Sheets("ShimSheet")

    Dim chkbox As checkBox

    Dim i As Long

    Dim name As String
    name = ""

    For i = 1 To 50
        name = name & "a"
        With shimSheet.Cells(12 + i, 3)

            shimSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height).name = name
            shimSheet.CheckBoxes(name).Delete
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I saw the same problem here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/72201c7c-81e6-4f6a-b109-ddad86dc8e59/bug-naming-activex-checkbox-in-excel-2010?forum=exceldev . Apparently it is the limit.

Comment: you can see it directly in Excel UI, where my Excel 2013 limits it to 31 characters. You could use alphanumeric names: "a1", "a2",...

Comment: The Microsoft Documentation doesn't have any information regarding max name length, but I cannot find a work around to get more than 33 characters. If it is not necessary to use "a" repeatedly, @user3598756 has a great suggestion!

Comment: @PartyHatPanda its not about repeating A. This was just my testcase to figure out why is excel failing :) My thought was to have some checkbox tree structure, with parent<>child reference. But names was too long...

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you face such kind of limits, simply use the inbuilt office help. However to make the best use of help in your case, manually try to change the name of the control and you will see an error as shown below

[image]

Simply click on help and it will take you to the relevant MSDN page in you have internet connectivity :)

Please refer to the link [Not a legal object name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251363(v=office.15).aspx)

In case the link dies

> Not a legal object name: 'item
>
> Office 2013 and later Other Versions
>
> Form and control names must start with a letter and can be a maximum
>   of 40 characters — including letters, numbers, and underscores (_).
>   Note that the Name property of a form or control is different from the
>   Label properties — Caption, Text, and Value — that label or display
>   the contents of a control at run time. These properties can be
>   restricted keywords, can begin with a number, and can contain
>   nonalphanumeric characters.

Comment: Good point, i was just trying to type longer name in Excel manualy (and everything was okay). Checkbox was even created with that name, but after that i cannot acces him.